# How to save log in a file on device

Tags: android, file, save, logging

I want to save the battery log in a file on a device. I don't want to use adb logcat. And i should be able to start and stop saving the log. Please any help or tips would do. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ! Sorry my bad its ambiguous. It basically is a log of battery voltage, state of discharge and some other values like battery temperature etc. I have written the program to get those values but now i want the program to save and append them in a file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Log4j in your android code refer  http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html.